# UITabBar in StoryBoard with 5 buttons. How to go from one to a ViewController that's pushed from a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios5, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, xcode-storyboard

I have a Storyboard with one main ViewController. This ViewController is a Tab Bar controller, with 5 buttons. Let's focus on the two first

The 1st button does a segue to a UINavigationController. Working fine and shows UIVC1. From here, I can push UIVC2. Fine too.

I've made a segue from the main UITabBarController to UIVC2. It even shows the Tab Bar Item, in Storyboard editor. But it doesn't show up in the simulator.

So, can how can I show in my second button o the UITabBarController a UIViewController that I want to "recycle"?

Thanks